Varnish: Backend returns 503 even though it is healthy
I have a simple Express server running at https://img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev and I would like to use Varnish to cache requests (both on fly.io).
The backend looks healthy (according to the probe results), but as soon as I send a request to Varnish, it returns "Error 503 Backend fetch failed".
Fetching from the backend works as expected: curl http://img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev:80 (it returns a content-type of image/webp).
Here's my default.vcl:
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
  .host = "img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev";
  .port = "80";
  .probe = {
    .url = "/";
    .timeout = 5s;
    .interval = 20s;
    .window = 10;
    .threshold = 3;
  }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.x-cache;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    set req.http.x-cache = "hit";
}

sub vcl_miss {
    set req.http.x-cache = "miss";
}

sub vcl_pass {
    set req.http.x-cache = "pass";
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    set req.http.x-cache = "pipe uncacheable";
}

sub vcl_synth {
    set req.http.x-cache = "synth synth";
    set resp.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.uncacheable) {
        set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " uncacheable" ;
    } else {
        set req.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache + " cached" ;
    }
    set resp.http.x-cache = req.http.x-cache;
}

And my Dockerfile:
# See https://til.simonwillison.net/fly/varnish-on-fly
FROM varnish
COPY default.vcl /etc/varnish/
USER varnish
ENTRYPOINT [ \
    "varnishd", "-F", \
    "-f", "/etc/varnish/default.vcl", \
    "-a", "http=:8080,HTTP", \
    "-s", "malloc,256M", \
    "-T", "none" \
]

Calling varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health on the server returns a healthy backend: 0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 3 10 0.227228 0.214281 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
However, fetching from Varnish (curl -v http://image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev) returns:
< HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
< date: Tue, 14 May 2024 14:40:15 GMT
< server: Fly/d5207058 (2024-05-13)
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< retry-after: 5
< x-varnish: 5
< age: 0
< via: 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5), 1.1 fly.io
< x-cache: misss cached
< content-length: 278
< connection: keep-alive
< fly-request-id: 01HXVRR0V652Q4174W4FAFN4CB-fra
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>503 Backend fetch failed</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 503 Backend fetch failed</h1>
    <p>Backend fetch failed</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: 6</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>

Inspecting the request through varnishlog -v gives me:
varnishlog -v
*              << BeReq    >>   32774     
-        32774 Begin          b bereq 32773 fetch
-        32774 VCL_use        b boot
-        32774 Timestamp      b Start: 1715976122.825963 0.000000 0.000000
-        32774 BereqMethod    b GET
-        32774 BereqURL       b /
-        32774 BereqProtocol  b HTTP/1.1
-        32774 BereqHeader    b pragma: no-cache
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
-        32774 BereqHeader    b dnt: 1
-        32774 BereqHeader    b x-request-start: t=1715976122809682
-        32774 BereqHeader    b user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-        32774 BereqHeader    b accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-site: none
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-user: ?1
-        32774 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-dest: document
-        32774 BereqHeader    b accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-CH;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
-        32774 BereqHeader    b priority: u=0, i
-        32774 BereqHeader    b host: image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-client-ip: 83.150.5.242
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-forwarded-proto: https
-        32774 BereqHeader    b x-forwarded-proto: https
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-forwarded-ssl: on
-        32774 BereqHeader    b x-forwarded-ssl: on
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-forwarded-port: 443
-        32774 BereqHeader    b x-forwarded-port: 443
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-region: fra
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-request-id: 01HY42BCDSC16K3TD50YJY5EGH-fra
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-traceparent: 00-b72ca569a24131cc7ba7f2bb22abecf2-6e8c489b5b7428c0-00
-        32774 BereqHeader    b fly-tracestate:
-        32774 BereqHeader    b X-Forwarded-For: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150, 172.16.7.202
-        32774 BereqHeader    b Via: 2 fly.io, 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5)
-        32774 BereqHeader    b Accept-Encoding: gzip
-        32774 BereqHeader    b x-cache: miss
-        32774 BereqHeader    b X-Varnish: 32774
-        32774 VCL_call       b BACKEND_FETCH
-        32774 VCL_return     b fetch
-        32774 Timestamp      b Fetch: 1715976122.825978 0.000015 0.000015
-        32774 Timestamp      b Connected: 1715976122.826145 0.000182 0.000167
-        32774 BackendOpen    b 22 default 66.241.124.229 80 172.19.7.202 37422 connect
-        32774 Timestamp      b Bereq: 1715976122.826215 0.000251 0.000069
-        32774 FetchError     b HTC eof (Unexpected end of input)
-        32774 BackendClose   b 22 default close RX_BAD
-        32774 Timestamp      b Beresp: 1715976122.826340 0.000376 0.000124
-        32774 Timestamp      b Error: 1715976122.826340 0.000377 0.000000
-        32774 BerespProtocol b HTTP/1.1
-        32774 BerespStatus   b 503
-        32774 BerespReason   b Backend fetch failed
-        32774 BerespHeader   b Date: Fri, 17 May 2024 20:02:02 GMT
-        32774 BerespHeader   b Server: Varnish
-        32774 VCL_call       b BACKEND_ERROR
-        32774 BerespHeader   b Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-        32774 BerespHeader   b Retry-After: 5
-        32774 VCL_return     b deliver
-        32774 Storage        b malloc Transient
-        32774 Length         b 282
-        32774 BereqAcct      b 1197 0 1197 0 0 0
-        32774 End            b 

*              << Request  >>   32773     
-        32773 Begin          c req 32772 rxreq
-        32773 Timestamp      c Start: 1715976122.825851 0.000000 0.000000
-        32773 Timestamp      c Req: 1715976122.825851 0.000000 0.000000
-        32773 VCL_use        c boot
-        32773 ReqStart       c 172.16.7.202 43330 http
-        32773 ReqMethod      c GET
-        32773 ReqURL         c /
-        32773 ReqProtocol    c HTTP/1.1
-        32773 ReqHeader      c pragma: no-cache
-        32773 ReqHeader      c cache-control: no-cache
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
-        32773 ReqHeader      c dnt: 1
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-request-start: t=1715976122809682
-        32773 ReqHeader      c user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-        32773 ReqHeader      c accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-site: none
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-user: ?1
-        32773 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-dest: document
-        32773 ReqHeader      c accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
-        32773 ReqHeader      c accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-CH;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
-        32773 ReqHeader      c priority: u=0, i
-        32773 ReqHeader      c host: image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-client-ip: 83.150.5.242
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-for: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-forwarded-proto: https
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-proto: https
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-forwarded-ssl: on
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-ssl: on
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-forwarded-port: 443
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-port: 443
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-region: fra
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-request-id: 01HY42BCDSC16K3TD50YJY5EGH-fra
-        32773 ReqHeader      c via: 2 fly.io
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-traceparent: 00-b72ca569a24131cc7ba7f2bb22abecf2-6e8c489b5b7428c0-00
-        32773 ReqHeader      c fly-tracestate:
-        32773 ReqUnset       c x-forwarded-for: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150
-        32773 ReqHeader      c X-Forwarded-For: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150, 172.16.7.202
-        32773 ReqUnset       c via: 2 fly.io
-        32773 ReqHeader      c Via: 2 fly.io, 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5)
-        32773 VCL_call       c RECV
-        32773 VCL_return     c hash
-        32773 ReqUnset       c accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
-        32773 ReqHeader      c Accept-Encoding: gzip
-        32773 VCL_call       c HASH
-        32773 VCL_return     c lookup
-        32773 VCL_call       c MISS
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-cache: miss
-        32773 VCL_return     c fetch
-        32773 Link           c bereq 32774 fetch
-        32773 Timestamp      c Fetch: 1715976122.826399 0.000548 0.000548
-        32773 RespProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
-        32773 RespStatus     c 503
-        32773 RespReason     c Backend fetch failed
-        32773 RespHeader     c Date: Fri, 17 May 2024 20:02:02 GMT
-        32773 RespHeader     c Server: Varnish
-        32773 RespHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-        32773 RespHeader     c Retry-After: 5
-        32773 RespHeader     c X-Varnish: 32773
-        32773 RespHeader     c Age: 0
-        32773 RespHeader     c Via: 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5)
-        32773 VCL_call       c DELIVER
-        32773 ReqUnset       c x-cache: miss
-        32773 ReqHeader      c x-cache: miss cached
-        32773 RespHeader     c x-cache: miss cached
-        32773 VCL_return     c deliver
-        32773 Timestamp      c Process: 1715976122.826412 0.000560 0.000012
-        32773 Filters        c 
-        32773 RespHeader     c Content-Length: 282
-        32773 RespHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
-        32773 Timestamp      c Resp: 1715976122.826436 0.000584 0.000024
-        32773 ReqAcct        c 1161 0 1161 279 282 561
-        32773 End            c 

*              << Session  >>   32772     
-        32772 Begin          c sess 0 HTTP/1
-        32772 SessOpen       c 172.16.7.202 43330 http 172.19.7.202 8080 1715976122.825804 20
-        32772 Link           c req 32773 rxreq
-        32772 SessClose      c REM_CLOSE 0.001
-        32772 End            c 

*              << BeReq    >>   9         
-            9 Begin          b bereq 8 fetch
-            9 VCL_use        b boot
-            9 Timestamp      b Start: 1715976122.921363 0.000000 0.000000
-            9 BereqMethod    b GET
-            9 BereqURL       b /favicon.ico
-            9 BereqProtocol  b HTTP/1.1
-            9 BereqHeader    b pragma: no-cache
-            9 BereqHeader    b sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
-            9 BereqHeader    b dnt: 1
-            9 BereqHeader    b sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-            9 BereqHeader    b user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-            9 BereqHeader    b sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
-            9 BereqHeader    b accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
-            9 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-            9 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
-            9 BereqHeader    b sec-fetch-dest: image
-            9 BereqHeader    b referer: https://image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev/
-            9 BereqHeader    b accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-CH;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
-            9 BereqHeader    b priority: u=1, i
-            9 BereqHeader    b x-request-start: t=1715976122915192
-            9 BereqHeader    b host: image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-client-ip: 83.150.5.242
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-forwarded-proto: https
-            9 BereqHeader    b x-forwarded-proto: https
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-forwarded-ssl: on
-            9 BereqHeader    b x-forwarded-ssl: on
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-forwarded-port: 443
-            9 BereqHeader    b x-forwarded-port: 443
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-region: fra
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-request-id: 01HY42BCH35QFJ7Y0R3KRTPYK9-fra
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-traceparent: 00-0d7d3240e34d50be2f68e4fdfcaeb9e6-0cf2586ae1b6da4b-00
-            9 BereqHeader    b fly-tracestate:
-            9 BereqHeader    b X-Forwarded-For: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150, 172.16.7.202
-            9 BereqHeader    b Via: 2 fly.io, 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5)
-            9 BereqHeader    b Accept-Encoding: gzip
-            9 BereqHeader    b x-cache: miss
-            9 BereqHeader    b X-Varnish: 9
-            9 VCL_call       b BACKEND_FETCH
-            9 VCL_return     b fetch
-            9 Timestamp      b Fetch: 1715976122.921375 0.000012 0.000012
-            9 Timestamp      b Connected: 1715976122.921518 0.000155 0.000142
-            9 BackendOpen    b 22 default 66.241.124.229 80 172.19.7.202 37426 connect
-            9 Timestamp      b Bereq: 1715976122.921547 0.000184 0.000029
-            9 FetchError     b HTC eof (Unexpected end of input)
-            9 BackendClose   b 22 default close RX_BAD
-            9 Timestamp      b Beresp: 1715976122.921739 0.000376 0.000192
-            9 Timestamp      b Error: 1715976122.921740 0.000377 0.000001
-            9 BerespProtocol b HTTP/1.1
-            9 BerespStatus   b 503
-            9 BerespReason   b Backend fetch failed
-            9 BerespHeader   b Date: Fri, 17 May 2024 20:02:02 GMT
-            9 BerespHeader   b Server: Varnish
-            9 VCL_call       b BACKEND_ERROR
-            9 BerespHeader   b Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-            9 BerespHeader   b Retry-After: 5
-            9 VCL_return     b deliver
-            9 Storage        b malloc Transient
-            9 Length         b 278
-            9 BereqAcct      b 1167 0 1167 0 0 0
-            9 End            b 

*              << Request  >>   8         
-            8 Begin          c req 7 rxreq
-            8 Timestamp      c Start: 1715976122.921303 0.000000 0.000000
-            8 Timestamp      c Req: 1715976122.921303 0.000000 0.000000
-            8 VCL_use        c boot
-            8 ReqStart       c 172.16.7.202 43342 http
-            8 ReqMethod      c GET
-            8 ReqURL         c /favicon.ico
-            8 ReqProtocol    c HTTP/1.1
-            8 ReqHeader      c pragma: no-cache
-            8 ReqHeader      c cache-control: no-cache
-            8 ReqHeader      c sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
-            8 ReqHeader      c dnt: 1
-            8 ReqHeader      c sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-            8 ReqHeader      c user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-            8 ReqHeader      c sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
-            8 ReqHeader      c accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
-            8 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-            8 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
-            8 ReqHeader      c sec-fetch-dest: image
-            8 ReqHeader      c referer: https://image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev/
-            8 ReqHeader      c accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
-            8 ReqHeader      c accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-CH;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
-            8 ReqHeader      c priority: u=1, i
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-request-start: t=1715976122915192
-            8 ReqHeader      c host: image-optimizer-varnish.fly.dev
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-client-ip: 83.150.5.242
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-for: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-forwarded-proto: https
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-proto: https
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-forwarded-ssl: on
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-ssl: on
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-forwarded-port: 443
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-forwarded-port: 443
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-region: fra
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-request-id: 01HY42BCH35QFJ7Y0R3KRTPYK9-fra
-            8 ReqHeader      c via: 2 fly.io
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-traceparent: 00-0d7d3240e34d50be2f68e4fdfcaeb9e6-0cf2586ae1b6da4b-00
-            8 ReqHeader      c fly-tracestate:
-            8 ReqUnset       c x-forwarded-for: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150
-            8 ReqHeader      c X-Forwarded-For: 83.150.5.242, 66.241.124.150, 172.16.7.202
-            8 ReqUnset       c via: 2 fly.io
-            8 ReqHeader      c Via: 2 fly.io, 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5)
-            8 VCL_call       c RECV
-            8 VCL_return     c hash
-            8 ReqUnset       c accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
-            8 ReqHeader      c Accept-Encoding: gzip
-            8 VCL_call       c HASH
-            8 VCL_return     c lookup
-            8 VCL_call       c MISS
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-cache: miss
-            8 VCL_return     c fetch
-            8 Link           c bereq 9 fetch
-            8 Timestamp      c Fetch: 1715976122.921805 0.000501 0.000501
-            8 RespProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
-            8 RespStatus     c 503
-            8 RespReason     c Backend fetch failed
-            8 RespHeader     c Date: Fri, 17 May 2024 20:02:02 GMT
-            8 RespHeader     c Server: Varnish
-            8 RespHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-            8 RespHeader     c Retry-After: 5
-            8 RespHeader     c X-Varnish: 8
-            8 RespHeader     c Age: 0
-            8 RespHeader     c Via: 1.1 3287147dc7e085 (Varnish/7.5)
-            8 VCL_call       c DELIVER
-            8 ReqUnset       c x-cache: miss
-            8 ReqHeader      c x-cache: miss cached
-            8 RespHeader     c x-cache: miss cached
-            8 VCL_return     c deliver
-            8 Timestamp      c Process: 1715976122.921813 0.000509 0.000008
-            8 Filters        c 
-            8 RespHeader     c Content-Length: 278
-            8 RespHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
-            8 Timestamp      c Resp: 1715976122.921834 0.000530 0.000020
-            8 ReqAcct        c 1135 0 1135 275 278 553
-            8 End            c 

*              << Session  >>   7         
-            7 Begin          c sess 0 HTTP/1
-            7 SessOpen       c 172.16.7.202 43342 http 172.19.7.202 8080 1715976122.921239 19
-            7 Link           c req 8 rxreq
-            7 SessClose      c REM_CLOSE 0.001
-            7 End            c

I don't think that timeouts are a problem, given that I'm using the same endpoint to probe and fetch data, because it usually responds with less than 1s and adding the following lines to the backend didn't help:
.first_byte_timeout = 120s;    
.connect_timeout = 60s;     
.between_bytes_timeout = 60s; 

Any ideas why the probe does not match the real-world requests?

Can you please add the full varnishlog transaction to your question, including all the headers? There's something wrong with the output and there might be more information in the logs than what's currently shown in your log output.

Indeed, I added the complete output of varnishlog -v above in the original comment. Thanks a lot, @ThijsFeryn.

I ran your use case in a Docker container using the following VCL:
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev";
}

I received the same kind of error:
--  FetchError     HTC eof (-1)
--  BackendClose   31 default close Received bad req/resp

This indicates that the backend doesn't even respond and closes the connection before sending any content.
However, when I add the right Host header, it does work.
Here's an example of a failed request:
$ curl -I localhost
                     
HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
Date: Sat, 18 May 2024 08:30:27 GMT
Server: Varnish
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Retry-After: 5
X-Varnish: 32776
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/7.3)
Content-Length: 282
Connection: keep-alive

Here's an example of a working request:
$ curl -I -H "Host: img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev" localhost

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
content-type: image/webp
cache-control: public, max-age=31557600
content-length: 13362
etag: W/"3432-ErSvtwFB99sNclnfEGZiVbVoDqA"
date: Sat, 18 May 2024 08:27:28 GMT
server: Fly/6751cc4d (2024-05-14)
fly-request-id: 01HY5D09XCGYN9G8E654RTSBJW-ams
X-Varnish: 32779 32774
Age: 214
Via: 1.1 fly.io, 1.1 varnish (Varnish/7.3)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive

The easiest way to fix the issue without being forced to use this Host header is by setting it in VCL:
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.Host = "img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev";
}

However, if your plan is to eventually use that img-optimizer-fragrant-cloud-4712.fly.dev hostname, simply changing the DNS to the Varnish server will do the trick.

Thank you very much, @Thijs Feryn, I highly appreciate your support! Your answer indeed helped; I could reproduce the problem and the solution on a local Docker container. I'm still failing with the container deployed to fly.io (same Dockerfile), but looking into headers might bring the solution.
